# Edit and continue in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to edit some code while debugging using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition? I can't find this feature in the options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's called 'hot swap'. You can compile your modified code in the middle of debugging and the class files will be replaced until you stop debug. Make sure to enable the HotSwap option in the debugger settings.

**Note**: hot swap doesn't work when you change method signatures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 'hot swap' addicted like me, you will love DCEVM (https://dcevm.github.io/)

Using DCEVM you don't have to reload debugging session almost never.

Unfortunately i haven't found anything like that for .NET :(

Comment: In .NET it is called "Edit and continue" and has been around since Visual Studio 2003 at least. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue

Comment: Edit and continue is not even comparable to DCEVM. One of few better aspects of Java in .NET versus Java flame :))

Comment: What are the differences?