# IntelliJ IDEA edit android code while debugging

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

It is possible to edit and continue android code while debugging in AVD? If yes, how can I setup it?

Comment: I disagree with the question being closed. Netbeans, Visual Studio, lots of other IDEs all have edit-and-continue capabilities, it's perfectly valid to ask if IntelliJ does too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893984/edit-and-continue-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't edit it while debugging. You'll have to re-make and launch.

Comment: this is also not exclusive to Android - IntelliJ with a simple Java project also suffers the same.  You are unable to edit while debugging.  For standard Java Projects you must also re-make and relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems with Android Stuio v2.0 and above, this feature (called hot swap) is now available.

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run